# responsive menu is not working by using css

Tags: html, css

1)The following is the code that i have used for the responsive menu bar.

2)Here is the pixel size (768px) but when i try to run this the menu is re-sized but

elements is not showed.

3)please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/N4LuV/ for full code.

4)Here is some code for idea.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
  <label for="toggle" class="toggle" onClick=""></label>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
       ----------------------
       ----------------------
       ----------------------
    </ul>
```

### CSS:

```
#toggle:checked ~ .menu { display: block; opacity: 1;}

.toggle:after {
        content: 'Main Menu';
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 33px 0;
        padding: 10px 50px;
        background: #51C1F1;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
#toggle:checked + .toggle:after{
        content: 'Close Menu';
    }
#toggle:checked ~ .menu { display: block; opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Resize your output area in fiddle, It works. Change max-width to min-width OR Add one more css media query for min-width :)

Comment: "is not working" - is not a problem statement. How is it expected to work..? and what do you mean "Here is the pixel size (768px)", you were saying it's responding (*from my understanding it's something that adapts itself accordingly all for all screen sizes, not for a particular size*)

Comment: Thanks for your replay.It is re-sized but if i click the main menu button the menu is not showed <li> elements, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

for your case Resize the fiddle output area to 768px, It will work only on that case as you have only one css media query in your code.

[image]

**OR**

write css media queries for all the devices to make it adjustable according to device.
Refer the Link : [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Try to modified in this way:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Replace the  and  tags after

2)Just like below and use same code.

3)Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/N4LuV/1/

```
<nav>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<label for="toggle" class="toggle" onClick=""></label>
    <ul class="menu">
       ----------------------
       ----------------------
       ----------------------
    </ul>
```